# How to stop Highcharts y-Axis bar-chart labels being skipped when height is small?

Tags: highcharts

I'm using [Highcharts.js library](http://www.highcharts.com/products/highcharts) and when Bar Chart height is small, `yAxis` labels get skipped. By increasing the size of the bar chart the labels appear again.  How do you avoid the labels disappearing.

See this jsfiddle for example - http://jsfiddle.net/VbecE/3/

```
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<h3>Why does this skip yaxis labels America and Europe?</h3>
<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 150px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
<h3>10px bigger and all 5 yaxis labels visible</h3>
<div id="container2" style="min-width: 310px; height: 170px; margin: 0 auto"></div>

$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'bar'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Africa', 'America', 'Asia', 'Europe', 'Oceania'],
            title: {
                text: null
            }
        },
        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            title: {
                text: 'Population (millions)',
                align: 'high'
            },
            labels: {
                overflow: 'justify',
                crop:false
            }
        },
        tooltip: {
            valueSuffix: ' millions'
        },
        plotOptions: {
            bar: {
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    crop:false
                }
            },
            series: {
                dataLabels:{
                    crop:false}
            }
        },
        legend: {
            layout: 'vertical',
            align: 'right',
            verticalAlign: 'top',
            x: -40,
            y: 100,
            floating: true,
            borderWidth: 1,
            backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
            shadow: true
        },
        credits: {
            enabled: false
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Year 1800',
            data: [107, 31, 635, 203, 2]
        }, {
            name: 'Year 1900',
            data: [133, 156, 947, 408, 6]
        }, {
            name: 'Year 2008',
            data: [973, 914, 4054, 732, 34]
        }]
    });
});


$(function () {
    $('#container2').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'bar'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Africa', 'America', 'Asia', 'Europe', 'Oceania'],
            title: {
                text: null
            }
        },
        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            title: {
                text: 'Population (millions)',
                align: 'high'
            },
            labels: {
                overflow: 'justify',
                crop:false
            }
        },
        tooltip: {
            valueSuffix: ' millions'
        },
        plotOptions: {
            bar: {
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    crop:false
                }
            },
            series: {
                dataLabels:{
                    crop:false}
            }
        },
        legend: {
            layout: 'vertical',
            align: 'right',
            verticalAlign: 'top',
            x: -40,
            y: 100,
            floating: true,
            borderWidth: 1,
            backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
            shadow: true
        },
        credits: {
            enabled: false
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Year 1800',
            data: [107, 31, 635, 203, 2]
        }, {
            name: 'Year 1900',
            data: [133, 156, 947, 408, 6]
        }, {
            name: 'Year 2008',
            data: [973, 914, 4054, 732, 34]
        }]
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You can set [step](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.labels.step) parameter as 1,

```
labels: {
                step:1,
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/VbecE/7/